# Short fiction in which the suits of playing cards (clubs, diamonds, spades, hearts) are used in place of some words

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember reading such a story, maybe in the New Yorker or The Atlantic, in the 1990s or early 2000s. There were hearts and diamonds and clubs and spades throughout the story (printed the same size as the type font, like wingdings or webdings symbols) in place of words. The story was written in first person. IIRC the narrator was dealing with a family medical situation at a hospital, something among adult brothers.

Comment: Can you remember why those symbols were used? Like did each one always replace a specific word, or were they meant to symbolise something, or ... ?

Comment: Even at the time, I didn't really "get" how they being were used, but I don't think they represented merely four different words (or maybe they did but I didn't realize it). Didn't know what they symbolized nor the author's intent. At the time, it was intriguing but I got no further than interpreting it as esoteric contemporary fiction. Hesitant to mention this because my memory could be way off and mixing up something totally different, but there is a possibility the story was some kind of riff on What We Talk About When We Talk About Love. But if I am wrong, that may throw off the search.